# htaccess "Satisfy Any" not working

Tags: .htaccess

I have enabled htpasswd authentication for my website, so the website need a username / password to be accessed. Now I need to allow one url without authentication, when i use "Satisfy any" directive inside virtualhost, the authentication is not happening for entire website. My configuration is below,

```
<Directory “/home/website/docroot”>
SetEnvIf Request_URI “^/source/notification/notify$” NOPASSWD=true
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName “Restricted Access”
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/htpassword
Require valid-user
AllowOverride all
Allow from env=NOPASSWD
Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Is something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: The first thing I've noticed in your code is the wrong use of quotes. You used typographic quotes to quote "Restricted Access" - but usually those characters are not quote at all when it comes to software.

Comment: Are you still using Apache 2.2 or earlier or can you use the new much simpler `Require` syntax that is now available in Apache 2.4?  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time